# How to approach or circumvent job sites that only offer a limited list of options?

Tags: resume, job-search

I've seem that most job sites only offer a limited list of technologies and past companies. This leaves very little room for personal marketing. I can make a killer CV but I'm at a loss at how to get a job in such a rigid format that doesn't let me stand out from the other 100,000 people using the same site.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I recommend just not using the job sites with limited options to build your CV. I've encountered some of these types of job sites too and I just don't find them worth my time.

Comment: Some job sites sure, but *most*?! Not at all. I tend to ignore any like that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question needs more details to avoid being closed for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these sites allow you to send your CV as an email, if they do, just do that.

Those that don't are usually not build to allow you to stand out, but to be searched through like a database. Either just fill out the form and accept that you don't stand out or move on and accept that you won't use their services.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you and these job sites have different objectives.  You want to find yourself a job.  They want to find someone (actually many someones) a job.  They don't have a vested interest in you being able to make yourself stand out because that doesn't improve their volume of placements.

I would suggest building out an online profile, Linked-In or similar, to showcase your strong points.  Additionally, being involved in open source projects will help you build your online persona.  Most hiring teams will be looking in those areas for additional information about candidates, so including links to those on your resume will help lead recruiters to a better place for you to shine.